# Python grab keyboard key asynchronously

Tags: python, asynchronous, keyboard

I build a python script that:

1. Read byte from serial port,
2. Parse the received data,
3. Write on serial port a reply response.

My script is a sort of equipment simulator to test a hardware board.

The script works automatically without human interaction.

To test some use case (e.g no response from simulator, send back a specific packet, ...) I would use the key keyboard to control the simulator behaviour.

For example:

- If I press the 'y' key, the simulator stop to reply to incoming messages.
- If I press the 'x' key, the simulator send back a wrong message.

Is there a way to grab the press of a keyboard key asynchronously?

With asynchronously, I intend the recognition of the key push in every instant of script execution, like an Hardware interrupt. Without the necessity to block the script to read input from the keyboard.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try pyHook module.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: pyHook requires pythoncom to work? Thanks

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: with `pythoncom.PumpMessages()` the callback is invoked but the code after `pythoncom.PumpMessages()` isn't executed. For my purpose (running code + grab key keyboard) I need a multitasking script? Task for the running code and a task for key grabbing?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with pyHook in mind, show us what you did and explain your problem and you'll get more answers / upvotes :) Don't forget [ask].